# Making simultaneous UPDATES by multi-users to the same record

Tags: php, mysql

Using PHP and MySQL I want to track sign ups using a PARENT and multi-CHILD relationship. 
A problem occurs if more than 1 user attempts to sign up using the same parent code. The parent will only be credited for 1 user and not 2. 
The solution as I understand it is to LOCK the record. Or use the server time and the record timestamp to determine last update.

```
#THIS IS NOT PRODUCTION CODE, BUT JUST INTENDED TO DEFINE MY PROCESS
#PLEASE ADVISE AND MAKE ADJUSTMENTS AS YOU SEE FIT

$sqlget = SELCT * record of PARENT and WHERE id is of PARENT
$ts -> timestamp;
$st -> servertime;
$af -> aff_number;
```

NOW I WANT TO CHECK THE LAST RECORD UPDATE OF THE TIMESTAMP OF THE PARENT, 
IF THAT UPDATE OCCURRED LESS THAN 10 SECONDS AGO - I WANT TO RERUN my $sqlget

How do i Convert $ts to an INT and $st to an INT so that I can run an IF statement 
to loop $sqlget IF my condition fails.

```
if($ts <= $st by 10 seconds) { wait 10 seconds and rerun sqlget } 
else { get current $af (INT) and +1; UPDATE record; close connection; 
META-refresh to next page; }
```

So does this process seem functional? Will this ensure that a PARENT is always properly credited for each child signup even if more than 1 child signs simultaneously? 
I don't expect multi-concurrent signups, but they may occur on a occasion and i must ensure that the PARENT is properly credited.

Comment: How are `PARENT` records credited with each `CHILD` signup?

Comment: The ID of the `Parent` is recorded to the `child` on a separate table. The purpose of this table is to just keep a count of how many `Child` belong to a `Parant`

Comment: So why not just `SELECT parent_id, COUNT(*) FROM child GROUP BY parent_id` as required?  Or else `UPDATE parent SET children = children + 1 WHERE parent_id = ?` as required, which will be performed atomically (concurrent sessions cannot interfere).

Comment: Can i perform that query to UPDATE the `PARENT` table as I don't believe it would be performance-wise to make that kind of sql request. A `PARENT` can have an unlimited number of children some and sub-children - That kind of query from multi-account can be very heavy on the db.

Comment: Depending on your indexes, it could be extremely efficient or extremely inefficient.

Comment: Why don't you just do `UPDATE parent SET children = children + 1 WHERE parent_id = ?` as proposed above?

Comment: Oh yeah I am - I Agree with you on that. I was just asking you to elaborate on your comment regarding indexes. I'm unsure of what that means. Are you referring to setting the `PARENTS` as the index of the record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand your SQL structure.

If you associate a "credit" with the appearance of a new child with the same parent ID, then any number of users may affiliate simultaneously.

Just run:

```
INSERT INTO affiliations ( id_p, ... ) VALUES ( id_of_parent, whatever_data );
```

and you're done. It is indifferent whether parents and children are in separate tables or not. The important thing is that *there must be no reference from the parent to the children*, i.e., your only reference is the parent's id in the child row. This way you have no concurrency problems on parent.

When you need to know how many children a given parent has got, simply COUNT them:

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM affiliations WHERE id_p = id_of_parent;

I suspect that you are now storing a counter in the parent row. If it is so, don't: it looks simpler, but the concurrency problems make it not worth the effort.

Comment: Yes my intent is to store the `PARENT` counts for first child, second child, and third child. I think performing a COUNT query on these records every time a `PARENT` wants to check their status is a resource eater.

Comment: Not really. If you index on the parent's ID, the load is negligible; and after all, you expect to have many more children than parents. So, it is best to simplify *children* maintenance.